# Rest API: Naming convention

Tags: rest, api

I want your's opinion for given scenario, while working with REST API.

Let's say, I have one route to fetch user details, we have some roles for users like `supplier, buyer and admin`.

> **GET:** user-details/{id}

In this case we have to fetch some other user related data, which is very less, if we compare `supplier` user role  with user having role `buyer` or `admin`.

Can we create route like below by sending query parameter to route to get each user details like:

> **GET:** users/1/supplier
>
> **GET:** users/1/buyer

--- OR---

> **GET:** users/1?role=supplier

If we introduce different function for each route, which will reduce complexity and any change request for specific `user role` can be easily adjusted.

Comment: Hi, If you are using single table for all users with a roles column then you don't need to pass roll_name with ID. Because there would be single record for an ID.

Answer (score 1):

Designing routes completely depend upon what kind of data you returning to the client and what kind of business logic you are trying to implement for each user role. But not prefer pass user role into the query string.

1. If you are returning different data for each role and you have a few business logic, It's better to define different routes for each user role.

   `GET: users/1/supplier`

   `GET: users/1/buyer`
2. If you don't have that much business logic but you want to retrieve same data with additional condition (want to add dynamically SQL where condition based on user role), You can fetch result with laravel eloquent way `->when` even you don't need to define multiple routes.

Answer (score 1):

If the user roles do not overlap, i.e. a Supplier would never be a Buyer and a Buyer would never be a Supplier, then:

We can get user role from ID in our API method and can create different methods to get details for different set of user data (based on the "type" - use Switch, may be)
Single API to support all user types would be fine: GET: user-details/{id}

However, if a Supplier can also act as a Buyer, then you should have different function/route set-up in place.

E.g. supplier-details/{id} or buyer-details/{id}

Having different routes focus on providing only specific data for the user type.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we create route like below by sending query parameter to route to get each user details

Yes, you can -- creating new resources to handle a new use case is a perfectly reasonable thing to do.

There *are* trade offs.  As far as "REST" clients are concerned, two different URI means two different *unrelated* resources -- even if they happen to have overlapping path segments.  That means that [invalidating](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) the cached representation(s) of one resource don't impact the other in any way.  So you can end up with a client that has cached representations of the two resources that are inconsistent with each other.

An alternative to consider is whether you want to have two *resources*, or one resource with two *representations*.  Having multiple representations of the same resource solves the cache invalidation problem, but you move additional complexity into the problem of distributing knowledge of multiple media types.

Answer (score -2):

in my opinion,
If "supplier" and "buyer" are sub resources of a user, than first approach is perfectly fine.

In second case "role=supplier" looks more like a search criteria.